How to check if a regex string is PCRE-compliant?
In Lua, is there a way to check if a string is a valid PCRE pattern?
Examples:
local function is_valid_regex(pattern)
  -- Check if the pattern is PCRE-compliant
end

-- Test
print(is_valid_regex(".*"))       -- true
print(is_valid_regex("[a-z]+"))   -- true
print(is_valid_regex("([0-9]"))   -- false (unbalanced parentheses)
print(is_valid_regex("*invalid")) -- false (invalid usage of *)


I assume that you will eventually feed this to a PCRE engine? If so, apply EAFP and use pcall(...).

Thanks to @InSync for the suggestion :) this gave me an insight on a possible solution.
One can simply use a regex engine and pcall (~try-catch) the pattern creation block.
Example using lrexlib-pcre library:
local rex = require("rex_pcre")

local function is_valid_regex(pattern)
    return pcall(rex.new, pattern)
end

-- Test
print(is_valid_regex(".*"))       -- true
print(is_valid_regex("[a-z]+"))   -- true
print(is_valid_regex("([0-9]"))   -- false (unbalanced parentheses)
print(is_valid_regex("*invalid")) -- false (invalid usage of *)

